# Wordpress (php) comments pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to show in the first page (of comments) the last received comments and in the second page the olders?
I used the settings -> discussion -> selected options.

With it i can select only to show first the last comments in **each page**, but i would show **all** most recents comments in the first page and the others in the second-third-ecc...
Is there a wordpress function for it? I tried to put hard code in "comment.php" without results for now :)

- I tried to use paginate_comments_links() with a lot of parameters but i can't get the result that i want...
  Anyone can help me with an example or another function or an example to modify "comment.php" or another file in the woocomerce plugin?
  Thanks so much!

Comment: Certainly, see Codex about [`paginate_comments_links`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_comments_links/) function, use it appropriately, change arguments depending on what page you are. Order them by date for instance to show recent comments.

Comment: Can you give me an example to have first more recents comments not only per page but for all comments... So a unique select order by id Desc for all comments or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by all comments? Are you trying to list all recent comments on WordPress or trying to list comments on single post page? Please elaborate.

Comment: A list comments on single post page. i would have all comments of a single post page with most recents order. So if i have 20 comments, i would have the last comment in the first page and the first comment in the last page. And i don't know how can i do that with wordpress

Comment: The answer is already given use `paginate_comments_links` function

Comment: Could you make an example... I used paginate_comments_links(), i saw a lot of parameters for it, but i can't get the result that i want...